# Is isobutanol miscible with ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, alcohols, immiscibility

I can only find info on sec-butanol (aka butan-2-ol) and ethanol. I need to know whether isobutanol forms an azeotrope with ethanol. Can you direct me to a legitimate info source too, please?

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037838129180013L

Comment: From PubChem, 2 butanol is soluble in water, very soluble in acetone and miscible in ethanol and ethyl ether. If acetone is not a problem you can  dissolve in a little acetone then add to ethanol.

Comment: Unlikely. Compounds with similar polarity/chemical structure do not form aceotropes with each other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope#Mechanism

Comment: I've come to the conclusion the EtOH and iBuOH are miscible and will therefore not form an azeotrope based on the info provided here and elsewhere.

Comment: That's a _non sequitur_. Compounds may be miscible and still form an azeotrope, like water and ethanol do.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merck Index${^{[1]}}$

> isobutanol is miscible with ethanol

1) *O'Neil, M.J. (ed.). The Merck Index - An Encyclopedia of Chemicals, Drugs, and Biologicals. Cambridge, UK: Royal Society of Chemistry, 2013., p. 953*